# sending an email at specified time and day via sharepoint designer

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list and i would like to send an email out suing workflow every friday at a particular time.
I have been sending email via worklflow but i can't find anything that can solve this request.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Workflow events trigger when something happens to the system.

The ideal way to solve your problem would be to create a custom job definition

```
public class CustomJob : SPJobDefinition {
        public CustomJob()
            : base() {
        }
        public CustomJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType)
            : base(jobName, service, server, targetType) {
        }
        public CustomJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication)
            : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase) {
                this.Title = "Some Name";
        }
        public override void Execute(Guid id) {
          //send email here
        }
    }
}
```

But maybe you dont have server access? So you need two things.

**1. A trigger list**

Attach your workflow to this list.
The last action should be to delete the trigger item. (see next step)

**2. A scheduler**

This could be windows scheduler or something else.
Set it to run every friday (or as you need)
It would call a script, that would create a new item in your list using web services.
That should trigger your workflow, where you send your email

Comment: Thanks but can the trigger list and scheduler be done using Sharepoint Designer?Can i use SPD workflow to solve this?

Comment: @Patrick: No. Even with @djeeg's second option you will need some sort of console app or something to insert the list item. You will need to write some C# code.